# Google Maps v3 MapView not taking all of parent view in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a fragment named GoogleMapFragment which displays a Google Map (v3) MapView. This is the layout that the fragment itself is using, which is then inserted into another layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The parent layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Overview section -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/games_overview_wrapper"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Details section -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/games_detail_wrapper"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/node_game_details_min_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Map section -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#d40707"
        android:id="@+id/games_location_fragment_wrapper"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/node_game_details_min_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Photos section -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/games_gallery_fragment_wrapper"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/node_game_details_min_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The individual "sections" are never visible simultaneously, but are hidden and displayed according to other events. The `game_location_fragment_wrapper` is the layout in which the MapView will be inserted.

Inside the "Game" fragment I'm inserting the GoogleMapFragment:

```
// Setup the Google Maps fragment
if (node.hasLocation(getActivity())) {
    GoogleMapsFragment googleMapsFragment = new GoogleMapsFragment();
    googleMapsFragment.setNode(node);
    googleMapsFragment.addLocations(node);

    getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.games_location_fragment_wrapper, googleMapsFragment, node.getValue(NODE_KEY.TITLE))
            .commit();
} else {
    locationIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    gamesLocationFragmentWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Everything works per se, but the MapView doesn't take all of the parent view, which then a split second after showing causes a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: View size is too small after padding` Exception.

[image]

In the screenshot, the red background indicates the size of the containing view. The MapView obviously isn't taking the full size.

Any tips?

**Update: Added relevant parts of the map fragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

    mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}
```

and...

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

    final LatLngBounds.Builder bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    int count = 0;

    for(Node node : relatedNodes) {

        try {

            if (node.hasLocation(getActivity())) {

                final double latitude = Double.parseDouble(node.getValue(NODE_KEY.LATITUDE));
                final double longitude = Double.parseDouble(node.getValue(NODE_KEY.LONGITUDE));

                final LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                bounds.include(latlng);

                final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(node.getValue(NODE_KEY.TITLE));

                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                markerNodeHashmap.put(marker, node);

                count++;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Double wasn't parsed right. Continue.
        }
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), UI.convertDpToPixel(getActivity(), 50)));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046704/illegalstateexception-view-size-is-too-small-after-padding can help you

Comment: Can you pls share the complete screenshot?

Comment: @sandy Consider sharing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us reproduce your problem. As is, the problem can be anywhere and that's probably why your question hasnt got the necessary attention.

Comment: Can you share your `GoogleMapsFragment` implementation (at least the map initialization)?

Comment: @antonio posted relevant parts of fragment.

Comment: @DhirPratap added a full screenshot.

Comment: Remove the min-Height attribute in FrameLayout

Comment: Replace your parent LinearLayout to RelativeLayout,  You have set the LinearLayout orientation to vertical so thats why it is behaving like this.

Comment: @ShahabRauf I set it to RelativeLayout and it's looking the same. Also tried FrameLayout and no luck.

Comment: @AshishShukla I tried removing the minHeight parameter but remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int)) regarding your error about java.lang.IllegalStateException: View size is too small after padding.

You can also check this [page](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4773) for more information.

Comment: That exception is because the view is too small, which I understand and makes sense. I would not have this error if the MapView would expand vertically to take all of it's parent's view. This is what I need to do. If I fix that, the exception goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below xml file and play with the visibility of layouts, set the height of the parent or make it match_parent with giving some weight in parent of this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
    >

        <!-- Overview section -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/games_overview_wrapper"
                android:background="@color/primary_green"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

        <!-- Details section -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/games_detail_wrapper"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/secondary_blue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        <!-- Map section -->
        <FrameLayout
                android:background="#d40707"
                android:id="@+id/games_location_fragment_wrapper"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Photos section -->
        <FrameLayout
                android:background="@color/text_grey"
                android:id="@+id/games_gallery_fragment_wrapper"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".YourActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_activityome">
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For fragment you need to specify which one is your parent.the activity the tools UI editor uses to render your layout (it will find the right theme based on the activity

Comment: This question is not related to the tools UI editor.