# Xamarin android:IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): View size is too small after padding is applied

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android

I am developing an android app using Xamarin Android. Currently I am testing on a physical device, therefore experiencing an IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): View size is too small after padding is applied while using the physical device. When using the emulator everything works out fine.

The issue originates from my helper class.

```
    double southlng = directionData.routes[0].bounds.southwest.lng;
    double southlat = directionData.routes[0].bounds.southwest.lat;

    double northlng = directionData.routes[0].bounds.northeast.lng;
    double northlat = directionData.routes[0].bounds.northeast.lat;

    LatLng southWest = new LatLng(southlat, southlng);
    LatLng northeast = new LatLng(northlat, northlng);

    LatLngBounds tripBounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest, northeast);
    
    _map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(tripBounds, 550));  
    _map.SetPadding(50, 80,50, 80);
```

`_map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(tripBounds, 550));` is the one throwing the exception.

It also happens on various physical devices.

Comment: That means the padding you set is too large and you should give a proper value of padding. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046704/illegalstateexception-view-size-is-too-small-after-padding) may help.

Comment: went through almost all articles, from the solutions provided, I can't find their equivalence in Xamarin.Android, since most are deprecated. @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

Set the padding depending on the width of device screen instead of giving a large number:

```
    int width = ;//map fragment(view) width;
    int height =; //map fragment(view) height;
    int padding = (int)(width * 0.12); // offset from edges of the map 12% of screen

    LatLngBounds tripBounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest, northeast);

    _map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(tripBounds, width, height, padding));
```

Refer: [Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int)](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/10)

Answer (score -1):

so for Xamarin.Android people, after long and frustrating searches, I finally came up on and everything worked perfectly.
`

```
    Resources res =  context.Resources;
    int height = res.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
    int width = res.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
    int minMetric = Math.Min(width, height);
    int padding = minMetric/10;
     
    _map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(tripBounds,width,height, padding));  
    _map.SetPadding(50, 80,50, 80);
```

`