# Android Google Maps moveCamera causes "IllegalStateException: Illegal height"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-android-api-3

When I call `moveCamera` on a small screen, it throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal height.

This is my code:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(
    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
        bounds,
        // Padding
        100,
    ),
)
```

I tried removing the padding, but it makes no difference.

I guess this problem has to do with the limited height available to render the map as this only occurs on small screens, but there is still quite some space left for the map to render so I wouldn't expect a crash.

**How do I render the map and move the camera to the given bounds?**

---

Dependency versions:

- `com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta`
- `com.google.maps.android:maps-v3-ktx:2.2.0`
- `androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-rc02`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046704/illegalstateexception-view-size-is-too-small-after-padding Refer to this

Comment: I faced the same problem already. My solution is checking if the google map fragment view' height and width are larger than 0 or not before moving camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the crash happened on `moveCamera`, the problem seemed to be caused by `setPadding` called above it:

```
googleMap.setPadding(
    0,
    topPadding,
    0,
    0,
)
```

The fix was making sure that the padding would not exceed half of the map size:

```
googleMap.setPadding(
    0,
    min(topPadding, map.height / 2 - 2),
    0,
    0,
)
```